# How Can I avoid the Trailing whitespace and produce the desired 8 x 8 grid in the code below using Python?, my code is below as well

Tags: python

```
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        z = i * n + j
        if z < 10:
            print(f" {z}", end = " ")
        else:
            print(f"{z}" , end = " ")
    print()
```

I have tried the end= " " method but I keep getting the whitespace error, I am a beginner thus I am unable to implement other methods to address the same. The image embedded below has the desired output

[The output required ][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/StAVT.png

Answer (score 0):

This approach creates the full matrix as a string `s` first and then only prints once in the end:

```
s = ''
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        z = i * n + j
        s += ' '
        if z < 10:
            s += ' '
        s += str(z)
    s += '\n'
print(s)
```